# Is there any way to disallow virtual cams on a site?

Tags: php, .net, web-applications, video-streaming, webcam

am learning something and wanted to know if its possible. Say there's a site which requires access to our system's camera, maybe a normal videochat site. Is there anyway by which that site can disallow virtual cameras? It should only accept real cams plugin in or builtin with the system.

I think that's at browser level and has nothing to do with the web application, what you think?

Note: Those who don't know what virtual cams are, they are simply software which enables you to stream recorded content instead of your live face from real cam.

Comment: It might be possible to get the MAC address of the device and create some sort of blacklist for virtual devices.  Not real sure though.

Comment: There are no virtual device, its virtual cam software.

Answer (score 0):

No. The browser has no way to tell the difference between virtual and real cameras.

Comment: just curious, could you get the mac address server-side?